# jsfiddle identical(?) fiddles with button to change text one works one does not

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

HTML:-

```
<h1 id="title">Javascript example no.2</h1>
<input type="text" id="myTextField"/>
<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="F_change()"/>
```

JAVASCRIPT:-

```
function change() {

  var myNewTitle = document.getElementById('myTextField').value;
  if (myNewTitle.length == 0) {
    alert('Write Some real Text please.');
    return;
  }

  var title = document.getElementById('title');
  title.innerHTML = myNewTitle;

}
```

When user enters text in text field and clicks button the new text will replace the title text.

This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oj847o3k/) works OK (thanks to Emad Elsaid: https://jsfiddle.net/user/blazeeboy/fiddles/).

This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/steveow/mbg1dkdw/) does not work.

It is driving me mad, please help.

**UPDATE**

I should have spotted the obvious mismatches in function name (F_Change vs. change).

The big lesson for me was to set jsfiddle...javascript...Load Type

from "on load"

to "no wrap - in ".

Thanks to all responders.

Comment: onclick="F_change()" not found, you need to name it onclick="change()" :)

Comment: The browser console is a useful tool you should get in the habit of checking; it makes identifying this sort of issue trivial.

Comment: @Daniel Beck Thanks. I didn't imagine it was possible to use the console in jsfiddle before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the way the Javascript is loaded into the HTML. In the working JSFiddle the script is loaded at the moment that the script is placed in the `head` of the document while in the other JSFiddle the script is placed in the body of a function that is called when the document triggers the `ready` event. These methods of loading the script are named "no wrap" and "onLoad" respectively in JSFiddle. Just compare the two snippets of HTML code below, taken from the JSFiddle pages you've linked to in the question.

The JSFiddle that works:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[

    function change(){

        ...

    }

//]]> 

</script>
```

The JSFiddle that does not work:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    window.onload=function(){
        //... *** LINKED ON STACK EXCHANGE - DO NOT UPDATE, FORK INSTEAD ***

        function change() {

            ...

        }

    }//]]> 

</script>
```

Because the `change` function is defined in the scope of the `window.onload` callback function it is not visible for the Javascript defined outside of that function. Therefore you can not call it from your inline Javascript. No need to change the name of the function, just change the `Load Type` (found under the gear icon) to "no wrap" and everything will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  Also I had to select "no wrap in body" rather than "no wrap in head" otherwise jsfiddle doesn't find the external scripts (THREE.js).

Answer (score 1):

The onclick functions have different names and F_change() does not match a function name

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
function change() {
```

to this:

```
function F_change() {
```

And change `Javascript` -> `Load Type` to `"No Wrap - in <head>"`

Comment: Thankyou, I should have spotted the function name error.  But it was the "No wrap - in <head>" switch that was the difficult one.

Answer (score 1):

change code to :

```
<html>
<body>
<h1 id="title">Javascript example no.2</h1>
<input type="text" id="myTextField"/>
<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Change" onclick="F_change()"/>
<script>
function F_change() {
  var myNewTitle = document.getElementById('myTextField').value;
  if (myNewTitle.length == 0) {
    alert('Write Some real Text please.');
    return false;
  }
    var title = document.getElementById('title');
  title.innerHTML = myNewTitle;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks elegant. But I was trying to get it to work in jsfiddle specifically, sorry I should have said that in my question.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML Onclick is F_change() but in javascript they call the change().So the onclick and function name is different.

So we can use the same name as the function name

we can use either onclick="F_change()" function F_Change()  or  onclick="change()" function Change()